# Contraction of loops on algebraic surfaces.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, singularity-theory, etale-cohomology

Suppose ${\Bbb C}$ be a complex number field and $S$ be a projective smooth surface over ${\Bbb C}$. We consider a finite etale Galois covering $\pi \colon T \to S$ of degree $d$. We consider the curve $D$ on $S$ such that

1. $D = \underset{i = 1,\cdots,n}{\cup} C_i$, where each $C_i$ is a smooth irreducible curve and $C_i \cdot C_j = 1$ for $i \not= j$.
2. $D$ forms a closed loop, i.e. the dual graph of $D$ is a $n$-gon.
3. Each irreducible component $C_i$ of $D$ splits into $d$ irreducible components in $T$.
4. $D$ can be contracted to a point. I.e., $\exists f \colon S \to U$ such that $U$ is a proper algebraic surface over ${\Bbb C}$ and $f(D) = {\mathrm{a~point}}$.

Q. For a given etale covering $\pi$, is it true that sufficiently many $D$'s satisfying above 4 conditions exist in quantity? Or is there any measure to size up the number of above $D$'s?

Comment: The problem is whether $D$ satisfies the condition 4. Generally, Mumford showed that the curves with its negative self-intersection number can be contracted into a point, but only the target is an algebraic space, not a scheme. So we must carefully choose such $D$'s as can be contracted to the algebraic surface.

Comment: Conjecturally, there would be enough such $D$'s satisfying above 4 conditions. Indeed, in the case that $S$ is a certain Godeaux surface, Asakura constructed such $D$ with each irreducible component being a rational curve. However, in this question, whether numerical abundance for such $D$'s are questioned.

Comment: On the kernel of the reciprocity map of normal surfaces over finite fields
K Matsumi, K Sato, M Asakura
K-THEORY 18 3 203 - 234 1999年11月